# Plotting line on chart c#

Tags: c#, charts

I made a scatter plot out of data collected from the user and I was wondering if I could add a line of best fit to the data and how to do it.

Comment: There is a full solution in the link:  [Plotting a line in a chart given the y intercept and slope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34554609/plotting-a-line-in-a-chart-given-the-y-intercept-and-slope)

Comment: machine learning? http://www.toptal.com/machine-learning/machine-learning-theory-an-introductory-primer