# define straight line with rough line?

Tags: object, image-processing, line, signal-processing

in the below image i have a surface which is not smooth ( i dont know its terminology).I would make a straight line at above of white object but it has rough surface.as visible, the whole object is not horizontal and it is tilted and its angle can be predefined and varied picture by picture.

I need a straight line representing this rough surface (in the red box) which is an average (or maybe something else than average). 
finally i need a curve y=mx+b.  could you please give your idea or help me how should i approach the solution.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What OS? What tools? Do you have the numerical data that creates the image? Do you have other sample images?

Comment: so you are looking for the [`line of best fit`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34554609/plotting-a-line-in-a-chart-given-the-y-intercept-and-slope/34558330?s=1|0.6304#34558330) ?

Comment: Is it ever rotated? Is it always the top edge? Does the white shape change size or position? Is it sometimes partially out of the frame? Are there sometimes more than one object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a rough outline of an answer, using ImageMagick which is installed on most Linux distros and is available for OSX and Windows.

First clean up the image by in-painting black all around the edges 2.5% in from the side and then thresholding to pure black and white. Also move to PNG format to avoid losses and errors. I would normally just trim the image by cropping some off the edge to get rid of your jaggy top-edge, but that would skew the y-coordinate of your answer so I just overpaint it with black.

Then slice into vertical bars, 1-pixel wide. This produces 394 files called `vbar-0000.png` through `bar-0393.png`

As an aside, they look like this:

[image]

Then iterate through the vertical bars looking for the first white pixel to get the y-coordinate, as we already know the x-coordinate from the number of the vertical bar we are processing. Suppress output for any lines with no white pixel in them else they would skew the curve-fitting. I convert the file to text to do this - see note at end.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Pre-processing cleanup
# Blacken in 2.5% around all edges and threshold image to pure black and white, and move to PNG to avoid losses
convert thing.jpg -background black -gravity center -crop 95x95% -extent 374x295 -colorspace gray -threshold 50% +repage thing.png

# Get height
h=$(identify -format "%h" thing.png)

# Slice into 1-pixel wide vertical bars
convert thing.png -crop 1x vbar-%04d.png

# Iterate through all bars finding the first white pixel in each
x=1
for f in vbar*png; do
   y=$(convert "$f" -depth 8 txt: | awk -F'[,:]' '/#FFFFFF/{print $2;exit}')
   # Don't output points for vbars with no white in them - they will skew the curve fitting
   if [ ! -z $y ]; then
      # Measure from bottom left instead of top-left
      ((y=h-y))
      echo $x $y
   fi
   ((x++))
done
```

That produces this output:

```
51 207
52 208
53 209
54 209
55 209
56 209
57 209
58 209
59 209
60 209
61 209
62 209
63 210
64 212
65 212
66 212
67 212
68 212
69 210
70 210
71 210
72 209
73 209
74 209
75 209
76 209
77 207
78 207
79 207
80 206
81 206
82 206
83 205
84 205
85 203
86 203
87 203
88 202
89 202
90 202
91 202
92 200
93 200
94 200
95 200
96 199
97 199
98 199
99 197
100 197
101 197
102 197
103 196
104 196
105 196
106 196
107 196
108 194
109 194
110 194
111 193
112 192
113 192
114 193
115 192
116 192
117 192
118 192
119 192
120 192
121 190
122 189
123 189
124 189
125 187
126 187
127 186
128 184
129 184
130 183
131 183
132 184
133 184
134 186
135 186
136 186
137 186
138 187
139 187
140 187
141 189
142 189
143 189
144 189
145 190
146 190
147 190
148 190
149 190
150 190
151 190
152 190
153 190
154 189
155 189
156 187
157 185
158 184
159 184
160 184
161 183
162 183
163 180
164 180
165 180
166 180
167 179
168 179
169 176
170 174
171 174
172 174
173 174
174 174
175 174
176 177
177 177
178 177
179 179
180 180
181 180
182 180
183 180
184 181
185 181
186 181
187 181
188 181
189 180
190 180
191 180
192 180
193 179
194 179
195 179
196 176
197 171
198 171
199 173
200 173
201 173
202 173
203 173
204 173
205 173
206 173
207 173
208 173
209 173
210 173
211 173
212 173
213 173
214 173
215 171
216 170
217 170
218 170
219 167
220 167
221 163
222 164
223 164
224 164
225 166
226 167
227 167
228 167
229 167
230 167
231 169
232 169
233 169
234 169
235 169
236 167
237 167
238 167
239 167
240 167
241 167
242 166
243 166
244 164
245 163
246 163
247 163
248 161
249 163
250 163
251 163
252 163
253 163
254 163
255 163
256 163
257 163
258 163
259 163
260 163
261 163
262 163
263 163
264 163
265 163
266 163
267 161
268 161
269 161
270 161
271 161
272 161
273 158
274 158
275 158
276 158
277 157
278 157
279 157
280 156
281 156
282 156
283 156
284 154
285 154
286 153
287 151
288 151
289 150
290 148
291 148
292 148
293 145
294 144
295 144
296 144
297 140
298 140
299 141
300 140
301 140
302 143
303 143
304 141
305 141
306 144
307 135
308 134
309 134
310 133
311 133
312 134
313 134
314 134
315 121
316 122
```

And you can feed that into `GNUplot` to get the coefficients of `y=mx + c`.

I have marked on in red the positions of the identified points:

[image]

When I convert the vertical bar to text, in the above, I use this:

```
convert bar-????.png -depth 8 txt:
```

and that comes out like this:

```
convert vbar-0145.png -depth 8 txt:

# ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 1,295,255,gray
0,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  gray(0)
0,1: (0,0,0)  #000000  gray(0)
0,2: (0,0,0)  #000000  gray(0)
0,3: (0,0,0)  #000000  gray(0)
0,4: (0,0,0)  #000000  gray(0)
0,5: (0,0,0)  #000000  gray(0)
0,6: (0,0,0)  #000000  gray(0)
0,7: (0,0,0)  #000000  gray(0)
0,8: (0,0,0)  #000000  gray(0)
0,9: (0,0,0)  #000000  gray(0)
0,10: (0,0,0)  #000000  gray(0)
0,11: (0,0,0)  #000000  gray(0)
0,12: (0,0,0)  #000000  gray(0)
...
...
0,101: (0,0,0)  #000000  gray(0)
0,102: (0,0,0)  #000000  gray(0)
0,103: (0,0,0)  #000000  gray(0)
0,104: (0,0,0)  #000000  gray(0)
0,105: (65535,65535,65535)  #FFFFFF  gray(255)  <--- Here is the first white pixel starting from the top
0,106: (65535,65535,65535)  #FFFFFF  gray(255)
0,107: (65535,65535,65535)  #FFFFFF  gray(255)
0,108: (65535,65535,65535)  #FFFFFF  gray(255)
0,109: (65535,65535,65535)  #FFFFFF  gray(255)
...
...
```

The little `awk` script just looks for the first occurrence of `#FFFFFF`, i.e. white, and then prints the y-coordinate which is just after the first comma on that line.

I'm no great shakes on `GNUplot`, but I made a command file called `plot.cmd` like this:

```
set title 'Plotted with Gnuplot'
set ylabel 'y-axis'
set xlabel 'x-axis'
f(x)=a*x+b
fit f(x) 'points.txt' using 1:2 via a,b
plot 'points.txt',f(x) with lines linestyle 3
set terminal png large
set output 'graph.png'
set size 1,0.5
replot
```

and ran:

```
gnuplot plot.cmd
```

and got this

[image]

and it tells me that the equation is

```
y = -0.26x + 225.2
```

**GNUplot output**

```
After 5 iterations the fit converged.
final sum of squares of residuals : 5200.82
rel. change during last iteration : -1.49004e-07

degrees of freedom    (FIT_NDF)                        : 264
rms of residuals      (FIT_STDFIT) = sqrt(WSSR/ndf)    : 4.43848
variance of residuals (reduced chisquare) = WSSR/ndf   : 19.7001

Final set of parameters            Asymptotic Standard Error
=======================            ==========================
a               = -0.260914        +/- 0.003544     (1.358%)
b               = 225.212          +/- 0.705        (0.313%)
```

Note that you could change the last few lines of the bash script to do all the plotting and stuff automagically at the end:

```
...
...
   fi
   ((x++))
done > points.txt

gnuplot plot.cmd
```

Comment: I never thought I'd see someone do any kind of useful image processing using shell script and command line tools. It made my day :)

Comment: It just demonstrates the immense power of ImageMagick combined with the Unix philosophy of joining up several powerful tools to do a bigger job. I could probably do it as a one-liner if I wasn't explaining myself all the way through and making small, readily digestible chunks! Thanks for your comment.

Comment: thank you very much for your great answer and idea. for this image it worked perfect. i have to say that i use matlab for this task. i also have some other picture which another object appear over the currrent white object. could you please give me an idead how to find their flat surfaces. i demonstrate with red lines.

Comment: Glad it works for you! I presume you are going to add another image to your question. If so, please add an unmarked one and a red marked one so I get a clean unmarked image to play with.

Comment: stackoverflow does not allow me to upload 3 images. i can only upload 2 images. i need the a flat surface for below white object (which you found it perfectly) and a line for bottom of that. in the link i show what line i need. [IMAGE LINK](http://de.tinypic.com/r/13zpowi/9)

Comment: My initial reaction would be to perform a *"Connected Component Analysis"* also known as *"Blob Analysis"* to separate the shapes. Then get the areas of the shapes and reject smallest ones so you only have 2 left and then proceed as in my answer here for each of the shapes.

Answer (score 1):

This is based on my other answer but I am putting it as another, separate answer because it uses totally different technology. Here I use **OpenCV Computer Vision Library** rather than **ImageMagick** to get the points I marked in red on the other answer. Then these would be fed into GNUPlot just the same as the other answer as I don't feel like solving equations myself :-)

I am not that competent in OpenCV and there may be faster ways of achieving the same thing.

```
// Get x,y coordinates of first white pixel in each column of image starting from top
// Mark Setchell

#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    Mat img = imread("/Users/Mark/tmp/thing.png",IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
    const uchar white = 255;
    int w =img.cols;
    int h =img.rows;
    for (int x = 0; x < w; ++x)
    {
       for(int y = 0; y < h; ++y)
       {
          unsigned char val=img.at<uchar>(y, x);
          if (val == white) {
              int inverted = h - y;
              cout << x << " " << inverted << endl;
              break;
          }

       }
    }
}
```